# How to do change image when users click thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change selected (or default) image when users clicked other images thumbs. I tried that with below codes but dosen't work.. Where do I mistake in here ?

Here are simple jquery codes;

```
 <script>
        $('img.thumbnail').click(function () {
            $('#productImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('60/60','400/200'));
        })
  </script>
```

and html;

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-5">
<img id="productImage" src='http://via.placeholder.com/400/200?text={{$product->product_name}}'>
  <hr>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/60/60?text=otherimage1"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/60/60?text=otherimage2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/60/60?text=otherimage3"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `<img` tag has no ending tag `>`, but that is not the only problem.

Comment: nope, I typed it wrong while copying and pasting. What are the other ones ?

Comment: If you listen to a click function on a class I think you would want to change image of the DOM element that was clicked on. So changing the ID of one Picture is not perfect.
You could give each picture an ID, but I would rather get the clicked img element inside the .click function.

Comment: @iCarnagy But İf I can do taht what you are mentioned it, I have to create as many functions as the number of pictures

Comment: @cervantes that's why I said that is not the way you want to do it. What you could do is to give each picture both image paths (for example as Data-Attribute) and switch between them onClick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `img` doen't contain class `.thumbnail` it is opposite like this,

```
$('.thumbnail img').click(function () {
    $('#productImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('60/60','400/200'));
});
```

And also check your `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You were not calling the right selector.

```js
$('a.thumbnail').click(function () {
    $('#productImage').attr('src',$(this).children('img').attr('src').replace('60/60','400/200'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-5">
<img id="productImage" src='https://via.placeholder.com/400/200?text=nothing'>
  <hr>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60/60?text=otherimage1"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60/60?text=otherimage2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60/60?text=otherimage3"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching the click event to `a.thumbnail` elements and than do a [jQuery.find('img')](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the thumbnail image's `src` attribute:

```js
$('a.thumbnail').click(function () {
  var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('60/60','400/200');
  $('#productImage').attr('src', src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-5">
<img id="productImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400/200?text=otherimage0">
<hr>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/60/60?text=UrunResimi1"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/60/60?text=otherimage2"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/60/60?text=otherimage3"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumbnail img').click(function () {
     $('#productImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('60/60','400/200'));
    });
});
```

Your jquery selector is incorrect. It should be in this format and make sure you have document.ready function to make it work properly in all the browsers online or offline.

[Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oq2ArKiHL1WRRcByhYcD?p=preview)